# System.Convert.ChangeType для DateTime

Tags: c#

Есть generic-метод для преобразования типов, для всех типов в принципе он работает адекватно:

```
public static class TypedConverter<T>
{
    public static T Convert(object value, T defaultValue)
    {
        try { return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T)); }
        catch { return defaultValue; }
    }
}
```

Вот скриншот отображающий ситуацию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом, конвертация работает для строки "04/30/2019 04:40 PM" но не для "30/04/2019 04:40 PM"ю Прошу помощи

Comment: **Всегда** указывайте культуру. Запустите код, установив русскоязычную культуру - получите один результат. Установите англоязычную культуру - будет другой результат.

Comment: Месяцев только 12, их не может быть 30. Или вы хотите, чтобы принимались оба формата: "dd/MM" и "MM/dd"?

Comment: Какой-то универсальный способ

Comment: Тогда используйте [DateTime.ParseExact](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8) (третью перегрузку), задав массив желаемых форматов.

Comment: Да, я уже понял, единственный вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Всегда** указывайте культуру. Запустите код, установив русскоязычную культуру - получите один результат. Установите англоязычную культуру - будет другой результат.

Месяцев только 12, их не может быть 30. Как я понял, вы хотите, чтобы принимались оба формата: "dd/MM" и "MM/dd"?

Тогда используйте [DateTime.ParseExact](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8) (третью перегрузку), задав массив желаемых форматов.

```
public static class Converter
{
    static string[] formats = new string[] { "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt" };

    public static DateTime Convert(string value, DateTime defaultValue = new DateTime())
    {
        try
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(
                value, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
        }
        catch { return defaultValue; }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
var dates = new string[] {
    "04/30/2019 04:40 PM",
    "30/04/2019 04:40 PM",
    "04/05/2019 04:40 PM",
    "05/04/2019 04:40 PM" };

foreach (var date in dates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Converter.Convert(date));
}
```

Этот код сконвертирует все 4 представленных значения.
Однако, два последних могут дать не тот результат, который ожидался. Это может быть как 4 мая, так и 5 апреля. Результат будет меняться в зависимости от порядка строк в массиве `formats` - какой формат *первым* совпадёт, тот и выдастся.

Comment: Да, это точно нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Есть решение, это указывать культуру третьим параметром.

> К примеру CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("Ru-ru");

```
public static class TypedConverter<T> {
    public static T Convert(object value, T defaultValue, CultureInfo culture) {
        return (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T), culture);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception выскакивает, вот доказательство

Comment: Данное решение не помогло

Comment: Это правильное решение, если _заранее_ известно, в какой культуре строковое значение даты-времени. Но суть вопроса, как я понял, именно в том, что _заранее_ формат не известен.

Comment: Но это странно, к примеру есть дата 10/12/2019. Она в той или иной культуре сконвертируется, но будет показывать разные результаты, что не есть хорошо

Comment: Я привел строку для конвертирования "30/04/2019 04:40 PM"

Comment: _к примеру есть дата 10/12/2019_ - да, результаты могут быть разными. Это нехорошо. Но если очень хочется, то нужно позволить автору (и пользователю его программы) обжечься.